# rewrite file extension from page.php to page.html in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using using nginx and wants to change my url from page.php to page.html
there are two things I want to achieve,

1. Change url from domain.com/page.php --> domain.com/page.html
2. The anchore tag in my page is domain.com/page.html but the actual page is page.php. I want this to work without changing my anchor tag.
3. I have a url like domain.com/page.php?get=value this must be like domain.com/value

Due to limited knowledge in nginx please suggest me the script

Answer (score 4):

When someone states that they want to rewrite a URL from A to B, they often mean the other way around. What they really want is for the URL address bar to show B, but actually access an existing internal resource at A.

From your question, I think that you want the URL address bar to show `page.html` but internally the `page.php` resource is served.

Let's assume that you have mixed content, some `.html` and some `.php`, so first you might want to remove any `.html` extension with an **internal rewrite** so that both `.html` and `.php` filenames can be tested. *An internal rewrite is one that will not affect the URL address bar, but just makes it easier for the server to internally route the request.*

```
location ~* \.(html|php)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.(html|php)$ $1 last;
}
```

The root location can then process extension-less URIs and test for the presence of `.html` and `.php` files, and anything else you fancy.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @php;
}
```

The PHP files are offloaded to a named location which contains the code to send the request upstream to the PHP interpreter:

```
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php /page.php?get=$uri;

    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
}
```

All of the above `nginx` directives are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/).